# How to prepare a Unity project for git (step-by-step)?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

What are the detailed steps necessary to prepare a Unity project for committing to a git repository eg. github? I don't want to store unnecessary files (specially temp files and avoid binary formats as much as possible) and I would appreciate a walk-through.

Comment: Oh definitely not. I'll stick to git, thanks

Comment: hi German, I was mainly just joking, but, svn is definitely easier for UNity projects.

Comment: german, I just realised you mention to HIDE meta files.  this is completely wrong.  Is it a typo?  Notice: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html "by selecting Visible Meta Files" and "2. Enable Visible Meta files in Edit->Project Settings->Editor"  It's a fairly basic point that you MAKE VISIBLE meta files for source control, you can see 100s QA on it on the unity forum. what's the confusion here?  cheers!

Comment: Wow! It's a very unpleasant typo on my side. Thanks for pointing it out (fixed)

Answer (score 264, accepted):

On the Unity Editor open your project and:

1. Enable **External option** in **Unity** → **Preferences** → **Packages** → **Repository** (only if Unity ver < 4.5)
2. Switch to **Visible Meta Files** in **Edit** → **Project Settings** → **Editor** → **Version Control Mode**
3. Switch to **Force Text** in **Edit** → **Project Settings** → **Editor** → **Asset Serialization Mode**
4. Save Scene and Project from **File** menu.
5. Quit Unity and then you can delete the **Library** and **Temp** directory in the project directory. You can delete everything but keep the **Assets** and **ProjectSettings** directory.

If you already created your empty git repo on-line (eg. github.com) now it's time to upload your code. Open a command prompt and follow the next steps:

```
cd to/your/unity/project/folder

git init

git add *

git commit -m "First commit"

git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git

git push -u origin master
```

You should now open your Unity project while holding down the Option or the Left Alt key. This will force Unity to recreate the Library directory (this step might not be necessary since I've seen Unity recreating the Library directory even if you don't hold down any key).

Finally have git ignore the Library and Temp directories so that they won’t be pushed to the server. Add them to the .gitignore file and push the ignore to the server. Remember that you'll only commit the Assets and ProjectSettings directories.

And here's my own .gitignore recipe for my Unity projects:

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
Temp/
Obj/
UnityGenerated/
Library/
Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# ===================================== #
# Visual Studio / MonoDevelop generated #
# ===================================== #
ExportedObj/
*.svd
*.userprefs
*.csproj
*.pidb
*.suo
*.sln
*.user
*.unityproj
*.booproj

# ============ #
# OS generated #
# ============ #
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: You may want to refer to [gitignore.io for some suggested ignore content](http://www.gitignore.io/api/unity).

Comment: I will add my own .gitignore recipe here, thanks for the advice (makes sense)

Comment: What are the .suo files and why are they kept in gitignore.io? Same question about the Assets/AssetStoreTools* folders(s)

Comment: .suo files contain your last configuration in the IDE (eg. which open tabs, etc) so you don't want to send that to the repo (it's specific to each developer) http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/652520-what-purpose-sln-und-suo-files-why-arey-outside-project-folder Assets/AssetStoreTools* is a directory that is created when you install the unity asset store plugin that allows you to send projects to the asset store (if you're a publisher you want to filter that out)

Comment: As of 4.5, it looks like this option: "Enable External option in Unity → Preferences → Packages → Repository" is no longer in preferences or necessary. I didn't do that, but followed the rest of this, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Why `Force Text`? I am using the latest Unity 4.5. Isn't it better to leave it to `Mixed`?

Comment: Because of "The Good" points in the answer to this question: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/222281/asset-serialization-mixed-vs-force-text.html

Comment: Note, traditionally it's a basic that you MAKE VISIBLE meta files to use source control with Unity3D.  (see any unity doco)

Comment: Just TBC for anyone reading in the future, there **was a typo** in German's answer.  In fact you must turn **VISIBLE ON, YES**, as it now says (2015) in the answer above.

Comment: By the way, confirmed everything works as is for Unity 5. Also, thanks a ton, German- this is a true life saver

Comment: I would love to see recommended settings for line endings, configured locally or with .gitattributes, for cross-platform Unity projects. https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: Why Step 8: delete everything but the Assets and ProjectSettings directory?

Comment: @bitstrider because otherwise you would push those files to the repo and they are not necessary to do version control on the project (they will be regenerated)

Comment: Why do you have to ignore Obj files with Unity?

Comment: @Waltari those are generated files during the build process that contain intermediate compilation files and debug info. They should obviously be ignored in version control (they will be regenerated when you build the project from source). Same goes for ExportedObj if present in your project

Comment: I thought obj was an 3D model file type?

Comment: @Waltari Take a look at the ignore file. It's not excluding .obj files, it's excluding obj directories

Comment: @German Why the "Icon?"?

Comment: Some OSes generate Icon* files. If your doesn't you can safely remove that line

Comment: I can't seem to find Unity -> Preferences?

Comment: Step 5: why to delete the **Library** folder?, your `.gitignore` is already ignoring it

Comment: @fguillen you don't have to. The point if you "can" if you want, it's just a note

Answer (score 23):

Since Unity 4.3 you also have to enable External option from preferences, so full setup process looks like:

1. **Enable `External` option in `Unity → Preferences → Packages → Repository`**
2. Switch to `Hidden Meta Files` in `Editor → Project Settings → Editor → Version Control Mode`
3. Switch to `Force Text` in `Editor → Project Settings → Editor → Asset Serialization Mode`
4. Save scene and project from `File` menu

Note that the only folders you need to keep under source control are `Assets` and `ProjectSettigns`.

More information about keeping Unity Project under source control you can find in [this post](http://v.zasadnyy.com/blog/mastering-unity-project-folder-structure-level-0-vcs/).

Comment: Awesome, I updated my entry with your recommendations!

Comment: The "Packages" section is missing in the Preferences in Unity 4.5. What does this setting do actually?

Comment: Take a look at the selected answer above, the step "Enable External option in Unity → Preferences → Packages → Repository" is not necessary on Unity 4.5+