# Is there a better solution than to connect assets manually in unity3d every time we update our working version from the repository?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mercurial, bitbucket

We are working on a project in Unity and we  have a mercurial repository on Bitbucket. We commit our changes to Bitbucket periodically and update our local repositories using TortoiseHg. So far, so good.

However, every time we change the place of an asset or change where on hierarchy it should be connected, we need to do it manually. It seems Unity does not find out automatically how these objects were connected on source device.

The problem does not seem to be file conflicts as we tried to pull to a clean local repository and the problem persists.

I'm new to Mercurial and Unity, but I guess there is a [configuration] file we are missing to include somewhere.

Has anyone worked out a better way to update the project so that every tweak works out of the box? This can surely save people so much time and facilitate using version control on unity. I appreciate any help.

Unity version: 5.1.1f2
Mercurial and TortoiseHg versions:  3.4.2 (both)
Working on 2 MacOs and a Windows 8 devices

Comment: Do you keep only Assets and ProjectSettings folders under source control? Do you keep .meta files under source control?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mercurial, but you could try the Unity related steps in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573405/how-to-prepare-a-unity-project-for-git

Comment: @Skyblade what you just mentioned actually solved our problem. We seem to have neglected keeping ProjectSettings folder and asset meta files. Thank you

Comment: @AdamH : thanks dude, I used the same answer (steps 1-8). However, somewhere on the road keeping Project Settings folder and meta files had slipped our workflow ;)