# unity can not import project correctly

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5.3.6. I'm new to Unity.

I can not import project correctly. On remote repository I store ONLY folders `ProjectSettings` and `Assets`. When i clone project to other PC and try to import it using the save Unity version - import fails.

I get the message "The saved project(before 5.0) does not match the launched editor (5.3.6f1)". When I click `Continue` Unity re-import project and .. all dependencies missing. GameObjects on scene have no `Scripts`, `Materials` and so on.

How can i correctly import project?
As I sad before on remote repository I store only `ProjectSettings` and `Assets` folders. Maybe i should save something else?

Comment: Did you store `.meta` files on remote repository?

Answer (score 3):

You need to save all .meta files to your souce code control repository too. They are Unity's way to identify references betweeen your assets.

s. for example [How to prepare a Unity project for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573405/how-to-prepare-a-unity-project-for-git?rq=1) for details about how to set up a repository

Comment: Well, this did not help me

Comment: No pending changes on the original PC where it is working? Did you try to copy _Assets_ and _ProjectSettings_ manually?