# Keeping your unity project clean when uploading to Github

Tags: unity-game-engine

At the moment, I just have my default settings for my unity project, which I then upload to Github. However, every time I change something, a bunch of meta files and other (seemingly) unrelated files get changed and are thus unstaged.

Wanting to keep my commits (and my local branch) clean, I searched online for some way to make unity work more efficiently with Github.
Following the steps in the below link, I was able to get a pretty clean commit, but when I get to the step about deleting the Library folder and letting it rebuilt, opening the project afterwards results in an empty scene.

[How to prepare a Unity project for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573405/how-to-prepare-a-unity-project-for-git?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I read some stuff that the library folder is not necessary, so you don't need to remove it, but then when I download the project on my other laptop, I have the same problem (empty scene).
Most of the information I have found doesn't seem very helpful or flat-out doesn't work.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: The advice in the thread you linked and in the [related duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18225126/5170571) is pretty standard. I'm not sure why it's not working for you. Are you sure you saved, committed, and pushed your scene files and project files? There's also no need to delete the `Library` and `Temp` folder except to confirm that these are temporary files that do not need to be committed into your repository, or if you are deleting these folders as a way to force a reimport of your project.

Comment: Hey Sonny. Yes I have followed the instructions to the letter, but as soon as I delete the library folder, my scene is empty when I start unity again.

Comment: @Davey That makes no sense. Scene files aren't stored in the library or temp folders, they're assets like everything else. The only thing I can think of is that Unity starts and loads up *a default empty scene* and not the scene you had saved (and you need to open it manually).

Comment: Hey Draco, Just tested it and that is indeed what is happening. Kind of annoying, but if that's the worst I have to deal with, I suppose I can live with it.

Comment: Thank you both, stupid that I didn't think of that